# MySQL Trigger - Update last row from table with average taken from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm having problems with creating MySQL trigger - I want to update column `temp` of last row of table `avg_temp` with an average from the last 144 records from 
 the `temperature_C` column in `stats` table. I am doing this through phpmyadmin before INSERT happens. 

My code, hope it helps to explain what I want the code to do:

```
UPDATE avg_temp(`temp`)
SET (
    SELECT `id`, AVG(`temperature_C`)
    FROM `stats`
    GROUP by `id`
    LIMIT 144
)
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

this however throws a syntax error.

If anyone could help me then that would be wonderful.

Comment: You should be setting the column. Try `Update avg_temp Set temp (...` I would also remove the `id` column in the inner Select. Still `Group By id`.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the right syntax for MySQL update to calculate the average of last 144 values, using a sublquery:

```
UPDATE avg_temp SET `temp` = AVG(
  (
    SELECT `temperature_C`
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 144
  )
)
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Yyou could use some subselect 
and for the right avg result you should use a subselect for get 144 rows

```
update avg_temp
set temp = ( select avg(t1.temperature_C)
      from (
        SELECT id, temperature_C
        FROM stats
        ORDER BY id
        LIMIT 144
      ) t1
  )  
  where id = your_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to want:

```
UPDATE avg_temp
    SET `temp` = (SELECT AVG(temperature_C)
                  FROM (SELECT s.temperature_C
                        FROM stats s
                        ORDER BY id DESC
                        LIMIT 144
                       ) s
                )
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

However, I would be very suspicious about your desire to do this, especially in a trigger.  Normally, the effect that a trigger has depends on the data in the records passed to the trigger.  I cannot think of a situation where I have ever written a trigger (other than for testing or informational purposes) that does not reference such data.

You appear to be using the `insert` as a timing mechanism.  Instead, you might just want to create a view that returns the average from the last 144 rows (or from the last 144 rows but one).